# Прошу объяснить работу цикла while

Tags: php

Конструкцию

```
foreach ($data as $k => $val)
```

я проговариваю себе в уме так:

> "перебрать весь массив $data и вывести его ключи в $k, а их значения в $v".

Также мне понятно с `for`. Но я не могу "проговорить сам для себя" конструкцию

```
while ($l = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r))
```

Это как я должен понимать:

> "пока $l равна результату преобразования объекта $r в ассоциативный массив?"

Но это же бред. Независимо от результата преобразования `$l` в данном условие будет равна этому результату.

Прошу объяснить это строку. Спасибо.

Comment: Смотри, пока присваивается, а не равна.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> пока $l равна результату

Не равна результату, а **присваивается** результат. Если хотите, то можно сказать так: *пока присвоенный результат не равен* `false` - *продолжать выполнять цикл*. Если на ассоциативном уровне, то можете представить операцию присваивания ассоциативного массива строк с тем, как вы черпаете кружкой (`$l`) воду из ведра (`mysqli_fetch_assoc`). Если в кружке после очередного зачерпывания (итерации) есть вода (`true`), можно продолжать набирать, но когда вода в ведре закончится - в кружке будет пусто (`false`) и столь интересное занятие нужно прекращать.

Answer (score 0):

Просто не надо читать весь while целиком:

> while ($l = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r))

Вместо этого читайте его только для результата присвоения:

> while ($l

А именно - "пока `$l` есть `true` или приводится к `true`, выполнять..."

Аналогичная проблема у вас могла возникнуть и с чтением условий. Например, популярный способ проверки наличия кэша и его создания в случае отсутствия:

```
if (!($data = cache::get($key))) {
    $data = Src::get();
    cache::set($key, $data);
}
```

Интерпретатор первым делом выполнит `cache::get($key)`, только потом присвоит результат в переменную `$data = ..` и только потом приведёт значение переменной к `boolean` (для этого и нужны скобки вокруг присвоения) `!($data ..`.

Просто следуйте тем же путём, что и пыха. В условии и в цикле проверяется нечто в круглых скобках. В вашем случае это присвоение. И тут важно обратиться к документации:

> здесь присутствует и еще одно значение - значение самого присвоения. Само присвоение вычисляется в присвоенное значение

(C) [Выражения](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.expressions.php)

Т.е. символ присвоения - `=` - есть выражение и его результат - то, что справа от `=`. Но удобнее смотреть на левую часть, а там у вас переменная. Результат присвоения в ней и рассуждать можно уже представляя что вы видите только эту переменную и ничего справа от неё.

Отдельно можете ещё попробовать переписать цикл на `do..while`. Станет сложнее читать сам код, но будет понятнее как производится присвоение и проверка выхода из цикла.